# Where can I buy Perspex sheets?

Tags: lighting, materials

I've been working on a lighting project that requires some light diffusers and after searching around I keep seeing people recommend something called Perspex.  My only problem is that I can't seem to find this material anywhere.  I'm in the US, does it go by another name here? Is it easy to obtain and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Home Depot has [frosted acrylic sheets](http://www.homedepot.com/Building-Materials-Plexiglass/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ1xihZbrdg/R-202038061/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053). The product description mentions that it's an excellent light diffuser.

According to Wikipedia's article on [PMMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly%28methyl_methacrylate%29), Perspex is a brand name of the same (general) material.

Comment: I went to Home Depot and bought something similar, a Plaskolite Acrylic Sheet - Cracked Ice.  This diffused the correct amount, the only issue is that it had a rather annoying texture to it.  Perhaps I'll go back and look for a frosted acrylic sheet.  I wonder if it would be very heavy.

Answer (score 5):

Perspex is a brand name, but I've most often heard the name used by British English speakers. A similar product is Plexiglas which is also a brand name. In the US, people use the word "Plexiglas" generically and I believe that's true of the word "Perspex" in Great Britain. If you go into Home Depot in the US and ask for Perspex you're likely to get a quizzical look. If you ask for Plexiglas, you may not get that brand, but they'll know what you're talking about.