# Where can I buy elbow grease?

Tags: materials

Whenever I'm in the process of fixing something or building something, people keep telling me all it needs is some elbow grease to fix a problem I am having. Although I'm not sure where to buy this 'elbow grease'. Can anyone tell me where I can buy it? I live in Los Angeles, California.

Comment: [Shopping assistance, product recommendations, or brand specific advice are considered off-topic](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). ;)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick then why did this question get upvotes? http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2924/where-can-i-buy-perspex-sheets?rq=1

Comment: I think there is a plume of it emitted by the La Brea Tar Pits.

Comment: There is room for humor on this site, I hope and pray??? DIY can be disheartening at times and having something for a grin once in a while is kind of nice.

Comment: The close reason makes this hilarious.

Comment: Please tell me this is a joke...LOL

Answer (score 2):

Elbow grease™ can be found in the [Shake a Leg store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_grease).

Comment: I can't seem to find where that store is on Google Maps?

Comment: @george:  Please follow my link.  (Elbow grease is a euphemism.)

Comment: @george, you're either incredibly dense and really need help (and I don't think this is the case), or trolling (trawling?) hard-working men and women on this site to score imaginary internet points. If it's the latter, please stop - it's not very funny at all. And just in case it's the former, please follow the links and advise that people provide, and you'll be helped.

Comment: Where they also carry Flight Line, Prop Wash and Muffler Bearings. We regularly send our newest recruits down to our local "Shake a Leg" store for the experience of collecting parts from our local jobber.